# Problems mapping objects with Mapstruct

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct, mapper

I've been trying to use mapstruct as it seems to be one of the most efficient ways to map entities and dtos in Java(Spring Boot). However, it takes tons of time to get it right. In my past project, I could successfully generate implementations after spending a whole day changing the pom. But not it's not working anymore and this is really weird.
I think configuring gets way more complex when the project also uses lombok, but it's a struggle either way.

Here's my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.1
 

xxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyy
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
dvdrental
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>

                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.18</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>5.4.28.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

With this configuration, mapstruct is generating the implementation classes, however it is not doing the mapping as it should; not setting properties into objects.

I have declared lombok as a dependency but I'm not using it in my code, I'm generating getters, setters and constructors manually in both entity and dto. I can't see what's wrong, this is a repeated problem. I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: You should remove Lombok and the lombok-mapstruct-binding if you don't use it. Lombok is not a library that you need at runtime, it's compile-time only.

Comment: The case is, I want to use it

Comment: The `lombok-mapstruct-binding` is not in your dependencies. Could you try adding it?

Comment: Are you using the Spring Boot Starter Parent, or you don't have any parrent? The maven-compiler-plugin version is really important. The `annotationProcessorPaths` only work if the version is at least 3.5.